# Get User ID from session in next-auth client

Tags: prisma, next-auth

I'm using next-auth with Prisma and Graphql, I followed these instructions to set up the adapter and my models accordingly:
https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/prisma
Authentication works but when I inspect session object from here :
`const { data: session, status } = useSession()`
I don't see ID
[image]

The reason I need the ID is to make further GraphQL queries. I'm using email value for now to fetch the User by email, but having ID available would be a better option.

Answer (score 29):

Here's the quickest solution to your question:

`src/pages/api/auth/[...nextAuth].js`

```js
export default NextAuth({
  ...
  callbacks: {
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (session?.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;
      }
      return session;
    },
    jwt: async ({ user, token }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.uid = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: This might have changed; it's showing up as `token.sub` not `token.uid` for me.

Comment: Answer edited to show token.sub rather than token.uid

Answer (score 20):

I just referred to the NextAuth docs [(this page)](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks) and finally got it working the right way

```js
callbacks: {
  jwt({ token, account, user }) {
    if (account) {
      token.accessToken = account.access_token
      token.id = user?.id
    }
    return token
  }
  session({ session, token }) {
      // I skipped the line below coz it gave me a TypeError
      // session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      session.user.id = token.id;

      return session;
    },
}
```

If you use TypeScript, add this to a new file called `next-auth.d.ts`

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';

declare module 'next-auth' {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      id: string;
    } & DefaultSession['user'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

None of these solutions solved my problem, but during debugging, I discovered that 'token.sub' represents the user ID. Here's what I did:

```
callbacks: {
    session: ({ session, token }) => ({
      ...session,
      user: {
        ...session.user,
        id: token.sub,
      },
    }),
  },
```

Comment: I can validate this being the right answer for this question as of now. Thank you!

Comment: do you store that token.sub id in the database?

Comment: @German no, I don't.

Comment: but you said it represents the user id. what do you store in the database as the user id?

Comment: This works, but it doesn't take into account the Typescript. The fastest way around it I used was extending the TS type of session and adding the id:
`interface User extends DefaultSession {
  id: string;
}

const user: User = session?.user as User;

const userID = user?.id;
`

Answer (score 10):

Here's the quickest solution that worked for me

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter"
import clientPromise from "../../../lib/mongodb"

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
      <...yourproviders>
    ],
    callbacks: {
      session: async ({ session, token, user }) => {
        if (session?.user) {
          session.user.id = user.id;
        }
        return session;
      },
    },
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

```js
callbacks: {
    async jwt({token, user, account, profile, isNewUser}) {
        user && (token.user = user)
        return token
    },
    async session({session, token, user}) {
        session = {
            ...session,
            user: {
                id: user.id,
                ...session.user
            }
        }
        return session
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm late to this, but I faced the same issue and this is the workaround I found that works.

So with Next.js@13^ or App router, they ask you not to modify the `next-env.d.ts`. They say it's to help them easily add updates/features of Next in the future, so they regenerate it for every build.

Specifically, the original file says,

```js
// NOTE: This file should not be edited
// see https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript for more information.
```

So the way around this is to create a new **module** with any name. Following convention, it would be a good idea to name it `next-auth-extensions.d.ts` in the same location/folder as `next-env.d.ts` and then add that to the `includes` property in the `tsconfig.json`.

So the following files are the end result for my config across Next, Typescript and Next-Auth.

```js
// next-auth-extensions.d.ts
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  /**
   * Returned by `useSession`, `getSession`, and received as a prop on the `SessionProvider` React Context
   */
  interface Session {
    user: {
      /** The user's id */
      id: string;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }
}
```

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "next-auth-extensions.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  ...
}
```

```js
// /api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import { db } from "@/db";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";

import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, user }) {
      console.log(user);
      session.user.id = user.id;
      return session;
    },
  },
  ...
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

I'm not sure about any adaptations for GraphQL, since I've never worked with that before but this works for me. Look at my `package.json` below just in case there might be discrepancies with regard to versions. Let me know if it works.

Note: This isn't the official way or anything, it's just something that I've researched and tried to get it to work, so if anybody has suggestions or anything, let me know.

```json
{
   ...
   "dependencies": {
    "@auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.3",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.4.2",
   ...
    "next": "13.5.4",
    "next-auth": "^4.23.2",
    "react": "^18",
    ...
  },
```

Comment: For next 14 app router and typescript codebases this is perfectly working answer.

Answer (score 1):

Very late for the party, but for those using `getServerSession` (in opposition to `useSession`) you need to pass in the `authOptions` for any of the solutions above to work and give you a userID.

You also need to move `authOptions` to a separate file, so that the export doesn't cause issues during build.

For instance:

`app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/authOptions.ts`

```js
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

type SessionProps = {
  session: any;
  token: any;
};

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session: async ({ session, token }: SessionProps) => {
      if (session?.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;
        delete session.user.email; // sanitize data for security
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  
};
```

`~/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.tsx`

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "./authOptions";

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

And then where you are using your `getServerSession`:

```js
import { authOptions } from "@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/authOptions";
const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
```

Now `session` will have an `id` field!

I'm still having trouble with the types of `session` and `token` though. Can't seem to appease Typescript...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can change the callbacks so it includes the user's ID in the session: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks.

You will need to change the JWT callback so it also include the userId and the session callback so the id is also persisted to the browser session.

Answer (score 0):

```
I fetched same problem. But now I solved the problem by using this code:

 callbacks: {
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (session?.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;// token.uid or token.sub both work
      }
      return session;
    },
    jwt: async ({ user, token }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.sub = user.id; // token.uid or token.sub both work
      }
      return token;
    },
  },

Thanks @Frahim
```