# How do you access session.user.id in nextauth?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am using next-auth version 4.19.2 .

I have a simple component that just displays who they're logged in as:

```
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react"

export default function LoginPlaceholder() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();

  if(session) {
    return <>
    
      Signed in as 
        userID: {session.user.id} <br/>
        name:  {session.user.name} <br/>
        email:  {session.user.email} <br/>
        
      <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
    </>
  }
  return <>
    Not signed in <br/>
    <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
  </>
}
```

My [...nextauth.js] just returns some dummy data:

```
      async authorize(credentials) {

        console.log("authorize script running...");

        const user = { id: 22, name: 'J Smith', email: 'jsmith@example.com' }
        return user;
      }
```

For some reason, my output only displays the name and email, but no id.

> Signed in as userID:
> name: J Smith
> email: jsmith@example.com

I work on a project, where multiple people in an organization could share the same email address (not my idea), so email is not a unique identifier for me.  I need the either the ID or the username, as a unique identifier, but I was unsure how to get that.

I also tried passing other data, but the only thing I can get to show up is name and email.

```
const user = { id: 22, userName: 'jSmith' name: 'J Smith', email: 'jsmith@example.com' }
```

But again, my components are not getting any values for anything other than name and email.

My question is:  How do I modify my code to display the username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [callbacks](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback), something along these lines:

```js
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({token, user}) {
      
           if (user?.id) {
               token.id = user.id
           }
           if (user?.userName) {
               token.userName = user.userName;
           }
           return token
        },
        async session({session, token}) {
            session.id = token.id;
            session.userName = token.userName;
            return session;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the help, buI'm still very new to this.  The documentation shows how to write the callback function, but I can't see how/when the callback gets called.  I added the callback to my [...nextauth].js (using your example)  How would I modify my component to grab this extra data inserted by the callback?  Right now, the data still shows up blank for me.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it!  My problem was that I put the callback inside the provider.  I was supposed to put the callbacks right inside export"default NextAuth({.../  Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey guys, i am doing all this, but the getServerSession still just returns name, email and image only. What might i be missing? I have the callbacks and when i log things there i have the user id there. Using useSession also has the id but not in getServerSession

Comment: Hi @Ashok. Your questions helped me find the answer! I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77950612/14195240 . But long story short, pass the `authOptions` as an argument to your `getServerSession(authOptions)`