# TypeScript issues in session callback

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to add the `id` property to the response of my API during login. I opted for using callbacks as suggested in this thread here ([Get User ID from session in next-auth client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70409219/get-user-id-from-session-in-next-auth-client)), but I'm encountering the following error. While researching, I found a discussion about this on GitHub(https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7132), and it seems to be a chronic TypeScript "bug". My question is, how can I proceed with this? Any suggestions, keeping in mind that my goal is simply to receive the `id` along with my response and manipulate it later. Currently, I receive the following API response:

[image]

## ERROR:

[image]

## The error starts inside the callback

```
callbacks: {
      session: async ({ session, token }) => {
        if (session?.user) {
          session.user.id = token.sub;
        }
        return session;
      },
      jwt: async ({ user, token }) => {
        if (user) {
          token.sub = user.id;
        }
        return token;
      },
  },
```

## Next Auth configuration file

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma as any),
  providers:[
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
    }),
    CredentialProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        name: {label: "Name", type: "text", placeholder: "John Due"},
        email: {label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith"},
        password: {label: "Password", type: "password", placeholder: "password"},
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req): Promise<any>{
        console.log("Authorize method", credentials)
        
        if(!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) throw new Error("Dados de login necessarios")
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where:{
            email: credentials?.email
          }
        })
        if(!user || !user.hashedPassword) {
          throw new Error("Usuário não registrado")
        }

        const matchPassword = await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.hashedPassword);
        if(!matchPassword)
         throw new Error("Senha incorreta")

        return user
      }
    })
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 60 * 60,
  },
  jwt: { encode, decode },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  callbacks: {
      session: async ({ session, token }) => {
        if (session?.user) {
          session.user.id = token.sub;
        }
        return session;
      },
      jwt: async ({ user, token }) => {
        if (user) {
          token.sub = user.id;
        }
        return token;
      },
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  pages: {
    signIn: "/dashboard"
  }
}
```

- I tried reading the Next Auth documentation, but I couldn't find anything specific for this.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is just a typescript error, because session.user doesn't include  userId natively. So start by extending Session and JWT types in a next-auth.d.ts:

```
import { EnumRole } from "@prisma/client"
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth"
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt"
import { Provider } from "next-auth/providers"

declare module "next-auth" {
  /**
   * Returned by `useSession`, `getSession` and received as a prop on the `SessionProvider` React Context
   */
  interface Session extends DefaultSession {
    user: {
      /** Id is the key you want to use for id in session */
      id: string;
    } & DefaultSession["user"]
  }
}

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
    /** Returned by the `jwt` callback and `getToken`, when using JWT sessions */
    interface JWT {
      /** Sub is the key you want to use for user id in JWT */
      sub: string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the solution was accurate!